# Sort Google Sheets spreadsheet by date, not by string

Tags: sorting, date, google-sheets

I use Google Sheets to keep a list of applications I am doing. In each row there is a date field. I want to sort by date now. The first row is frozen using `View - Freeze - 1 row`. When I select the whole table, press `Data - Sort range...` and then check `Data has header row` the sheet is sorted. But not by date but by string. The format of the cells is date. Is only string sorting possible? If yes, I would have to reformat the whole document to dates like `2017-01-11`, correct?

Comment: No repro. Sorting by dates works fine in my spreadsheet. You may want to share a sample sheet where you see a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to replace the <kbd>.</kbd> by <kbd>/</kbd>. Seems as if the common german format using <kbd>.</kbd> is not yet supported. Make sure the date is recognized as date. If the cell is right-aligned it worked, if not it did not work.

[image: Do not use . but /]

I learned that you can create a custom date format using the <kbd>.</kbd>.

[image: More date and time formats...]

[image: Custom date and time formats]

Now the date is entered **10/01/2017** but displayed **10.01.2017**. Just the way I wanted.

[image: Sorted dates]